# How do you retrieve the type of an object in Swift?

Tags: swift

I cannot seem to find a function or method that returns the type of an object in Swift.

How does one retrieve the type or class of an object in Swift?

I tried using Obj-C classes which obviously did not work.

In python you have things like `type` or `isinstance`

In Javascript you have `constructor`

Answer (score 11):

If you just need to check an object's type, you can use the *type check operator*, `is`, as in:

```
if myObject is UIView {
    // do something
}
```

If you want to try to call a method on the object but you aren't sure of the class, *downcast* the object to the type you need, like this:

```
if let myView = myObject as? UIView {
    myView.layer.backgroundColor = myColor
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for `dynamicType`?

```
someInstance.dynamicType.printClassName()
```

Comment: `printClassName()` is not part of Swift. It's from the Swift documentation sample code.