# How to determine if two objects are of the same type in Swift

Tags: swift

There's lots of past questions relating to this but all the ones I could find are for when you want to determine if an object is of a certain type of class (`if myClassInstance is MyClassType {...}`).

I want to know how I can determine if object A and object B are of the same class type without having to know/specify what that type is.

Comment: Couldn't you try to assign one object to the other or see if they are equal? If that succeeds, they are of the same type.

Comment: Specifically see this answer to the above linked Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40113416/2976878

Comment: `A.dynamicType === B.dynamicType `?

Comment: It's as simple as `type(of: A) == type(of: B)`

Comment: @Rahul `.dynamicType` has been changed in Swift 3 to `type(of:)`

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected - `.classForCoder` only works for NSObjectProtocol conforming types.

Better answers are available.

<s>This might do what you're looking for...</s>

```
class MyClassTypeA: NSObject {

}

class MyClassTypeB: NSObject {

}

var a = MyClassTypeA()
var b = MyClassTypeB()
var c = MyClassTypeB()

print(a.isKind(of: b.classForCoder))
print(a.isKind(of: c.classForCoder))
print(b.isKind(of: c.classForCoder))
```

Comment: This only works for `NSObjectProtocol` conforming types.