# how to get type of a variable in swift

Tags: swift

Every variable in swift has a type.

**var c: Int = 0 // type is Int**

**var d: (Int,(String,Double)) // type is (Int,(String,Double))**

how can I get type of a variable. See example below.

```
func retSomeThing ()-> ((Int,(String,b: Int))){
    return(10,("something",b: 56))
}

var a = retSomeThing()
var b = retSomeThing()
if (a.type.equal(b.type)) { // my problem is here.
    print("Hala Madrid")
}
```

I used this code

```
a.dynamicType
```

But it has shown : value of tuple type '(Int, (String, b: Int))' has no member 'dynamicType'

Comment: I don't see how your example ilustrates the need to get the dynamic types of `a` and `b` – you already know they're the same type.

Comment: @Hamish Yes I know the type in this example. But I need to get type of tuple variables.

Comment: Specifically see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40113416/2976878) to the linked Q&A.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks :))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the type of any variable using `is` keyword.

```
var a = 0
var b = "demo"
if (a is Int) { 
    print("It's an Int")
}

if (b is String) { 
    print("It's a String")
}
```

To compare any complex type, you can use below method:

```
if type(of: abc) == type(of: def) {
    print("matching type")
} else {
    print("something else")
}
```

Comment: 'is' only is not suitable for tuple valuses

Comment: @AmirShabani Check the updated Answer

Comment: dont you have extra parenthesis in this code?

Comment: @Olympiloutre Thanks for pointing it out. Answer updated :)