# Match the data type of a object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, types

How to match the data type of a object in Swift?

Like:

```
var xyz : Any
    xyz = 1;
    switch xyz
 {
    case let x where xyz as?AnyObject[]:
        println("\(x) is AnyObject Type")
    case let x where xyz as?String[]:
        println("\(x) is String Type")
    case let x where xyz as?Int[]:
        println("\(x) is Int Type")
    case let x where xyz as?Double[]:
        println("\(x) is Double Type")
    case let x where xyz as?Float[]:
        println("\(x) is Float Type")
    default:println("None")
    }
```

In this case switch case run default case

Comment: See [the answer to this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift

Comment: yes, it runs the `default:`, because the `xzy` is not an array on any level, therefore the `default:` branch will match only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change `var xyz : AnyObject` to `var xyz : Any` and add it will match to this case

```
case let x as Int:
```

---

from REPL

```
  1> var a : Any = 1
a: Int = <read memory from 0x7fec8ad8bed0 failed (0 of 8 bytes read)>
  2> switch a { case let x as Int: println("int"); default: println("default"); }
int
```

---

from [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_448)

> You can use the is and as operators in a switch statement’s cases to
>   discover the specific type of a constant or variable that is known
>   only to be of type Any or AnyObject. The example below iterates over
>   the items in the things array and queries the type of each item with a
>   switch statement. Several of the switch statement’s cases bind their
>   matched value to a constant of the specified type to enable its value
>   to be printed:

```
for thing in things {
    switch thing {
    case 0 as Int:
        println("zero as an Int")
    case 0 as Double:
        println("zero as a Double")
    case let someInt as Int:
        println("an integer value of \(someInt)")
    case let someDouble as Double where someDouble > 0:
        println("a positive double value of \(someDouble)")
    case is Double:
        println("some other double value that I don't want to print")
    case let someString as String:
        println("a string value of \"\(someString)\"")
    case let (x, y) as (Double, Double):
        println("an (x, y) point at \(x), \(y)")
    case let movie as Movie:
        println("a movie called '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
    default:
        println("something else")
    }
}

// zero as an Int
// zero as a Double
// an integer value of 42
// a positive double value of 3.14159
// a string value of "hello"
// an (x, y) point at 3.0, 5.0
// a movie called 'Ghostbusters', dir. Ivan Reitman
```

---

Note:

```
var xyz : AnyObject = 1
```

will give you `NSNumber` because `Int` is not object so it auto convert it to `NSNumber` which is object

Comment: change var xyz : AnyObject to var xyz : Any don't work       @BryanChen

Comment: It run Default again @BryanChen

Comment: thanks Bryan Chen,  your code in reply section works -> switch a { case let x as Int: println("int"); default: println("default"); }

Comment: @Bryan Chen what about NSDate?

Comment: @LeeWhitney `case let date as NSDate:`

Comment: @BryanChen Problem is it doesn't work if you get the Any value via reflection using this value: reflect(self)[0].1.value    println works fine but it will not cast as NSDate.

Comment: @LeeWhitney you can post it as a different question with more code and details

Answer (score 2):

Putting up an interesting usage of "case is" i.e., "case is Int, is String", **","** behavior is like **OR** operator.

```
switch value{
case is Int, is String:
    if value is Int{
        print("Integer::\(value)")
    }else{
        print("String::\(value)")
    }
default:
    print("\(value)")
}
```

[Similar Post with demo link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724527/swift-test-class-type-in-switch-statement/32497118#32497118)