# Need clarification of Type Casting operator in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, typecasting-operator

Why is the type cast operator (as) being used instead of its conditional form (as?) in this switch statement?

I thought the type operator could only be (as?) or (as!)...? The Apple Swift documentation does not provide adequate explanation about this.

Here is the example in the Swift documentation:

```
var things = [Any]()

things.append(0)
things.append(0.0)
things.append(42)
things.append(3.14159)
things.append("hello")
things.append((3.0, 5.0))
things.append(Movie(name: "Ghostbusters", director: "Ivan Reitman"))
things.append({ (name: String) -> String in "Hello, \(name)" }) 

for thing in things {
        switch thing {
        case 0 as Int:
            println("zero as an Int")
        case 0 as Double:
            println("zero as a Double")
        case let someInt as Int:
            println("an integer value of \(someInt)")
        case let someDouble as Double where someDouble > 0:
            println("a positive double value of \(someDouble)")
        case is Double:
            println("some other double value that I don't want to print")
        case let someString as String:
            println("a string value of \"\(someString)\"")
        case let (x, y) as (Double, Double):
            println("an (x, y) point at \(x), \(y)")
        case let movie as Movie:
            println("a movie called '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
        case let stringConverter as String -> String:
            println(stringConverter("Michael"))
        default:
            println("something else")
        }
    }
```

Here is the link to the [Apple Swift documentation on Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338)

Comment: Put up an interesting example for "case is" i.e, "case is Int, is String". Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724527/swift-test-class-type-in-switch-statement/32497118#32497118

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have found the answer yourself if you read the [note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-NoLink_198) on the bottom:

> The cases of a switch statement use the forced version of the type cast operator (**as**, not **as?**) to check and cast to a specific type. This check is always safe within the context of a switch case statement.

(emphasis mine)

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23) is an Apple blog post which elaborates on the difference between `as?`, `as` and `as!`.

Comment: That same documentation also refers to "forced version of the type cast operator" to be "`(as!)`" in many different locations within the document, so I can understand Walter's confusion.

Comment: Yes I have read that note. That note says "forced version of the type cast operator" which is **a!**. It doesn't explain why the exclamation mark (!) is not included. Also, your reference explains that **as** is a guaranteed conversion. I am not sure what that means. The Swift documentation only explains **as?** and **as!**.

Comment: The ! is not included because a runtime error can never occur - the `case` statement *guarantees* that if the `thing` is not an `Int`, the casting is not performed. I agree with you that it is confusing, though.

Comment: @Glorfindel thank you! thats what I was wondering :). In my opinion, Apple  made this documentation too concise that it just ends up leaving people, like me, wondering. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question :)

Answer (score 1):

The `as` in `case 0 as Int:` or `case let someInt as Int:`
is part of
a *type casting pattern*. In the [Swift Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AboutTheLanguageReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH29-ID345) the case label of a switch statement
is defined as

> *case-label* → **case** ­case-item-list­:
>   *­case-item-list* →
>   pattern ­guard-clause<sub>­opt</sub> |­  pattern­ guard-clause­<sub>­opt</sub>­ , ­case-item-list­

where pattern can be (among other cases)

> *pattern* → value-binding-pattern­
>   *pattern* → type-casting-pattern­
>   *pattern* → expression-pattern­

and a type casting pattern is

> *type-casting-pattern* → is-pattern­ | as-pattern­
>   *is-pattern* → **is** ­type­
>   *as-pattern* → pattern­ **as** ­type­

So you have for example

```
case let someInt as Int:
╰──────────────────────╯ case-label
     ╰────────────────╯  case-item-list -> type-casting pattern
                    ╰─╯  type
                 ╰╯      `as` keyword
     ╰─────────╯         value-binding pattern
```

Comment: This is really interesting. I didn't know this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Swift-Blog:

> It may be easiest to remember the pattern for these operators in Swift as: ! implies “this might trap,” while ? indicates “this might be nil.”

And there is the third possibility of a guaranteed conversion, when an upcast is done. For example `2 as Any` gets a warning when used with `as!` or `as?`

In case of the switch construct, the `case let value as Type:` never fails nor is there the possibility, that value will be an optional type in contrast to the expression `value as? Type`