# How do I use AS with a switch in swift to get the class type

Tags: swift, object, casting, switch-statement, control-flow

I have an array of `SomeClass` which is the super class of various other classes.
The array has all of those random classes in it.
Is there a way using switch (as opposed to `else if let something = elm as? TheSubClassType`)

In pseudo code:

```
for AObjectOfTypeSomeClass in MyBigArray{
  switch the_type_of(AObjectOfTypeSomeClass){
    case SubClass1:
        let O = AObjectOfTypeSomeClass as! SubClass1
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You were close.

```
for objectOfSomeClass in MyBigArray {
    switch objectOfSomeClass {
    case let subClass as SubClass1:
        // Do what you want with subClass
    default:
        // Object isn't the subclass do something else
    }
}
```

This site has the best rundown of pattern matching I have found.
http://appventure.me/2015/08/20/swift-pattern-matching-in-detail/

Comment: I see how it works, but logically I do not understand some thing with this syntax. For example, how come the `as` is not optional?

Comment: The as is not optional because you are pattern matching, not binding.  Binding would look like this and requires the optional cast: if let subClass = anObject as? SubClass { } . I admit it is somewhat counter intuitive since they both accomplish similar goals.

Comment: @Itay: For `as` vs `as?` in a case statement compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759778/need-clarification-of-type-casting-operator-in-swift.