# How to Add an Extension to Swift Array To Conditionally Append?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift3, generic-collections

Is there a way to do this as an extension to Array as opposed to a switch statement that's going to grow and grow?

```
    fileprivate var exteriorColorOptions = [ExteriorColorOption]()
    fileprivate var otherOptions = [SomeOtherOption]()
      : more options

    func add(option:FilteredOption) {

        switch(option) {
        case let thing as ExteriorColorOption:
                exteriorColorOptions.append(thing)
        case and on and on
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to just do the following with the right extension in place:

```
exteriorColorOptions.appendIfPossible(option)
otherOptions.appendIfPossible(option)
```

Note: switch approach came from
[Swift: Test class type in switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724527/swift-test-class-type-in-switch-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
extension Array {

    mutating func appendIfPossible<T>(newElement: T) {
        if let e = newElement as? Element {
            append(e)
        }
    }
}
```

The conditional cast `newElement as? Element` succeeds if the
new element conforms to or is an instance of (a subclass of) the arrays element type `Element`.

Example:

```
class A {}
class B: A {}
class C {}

var array: [A] = []

array.appendIfPossible(newElement: B())
print(array) // [B]

array.appendIfPossible(newElement: C())
print(array) // [B]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is correct but maybe not exactly what you want:

```
  extension Array {
    mutating func safeAppend(newElement: Element?) {
      if let element = newElement {
        append(element)
    }
  }
```

This one will throw a compile time error in case you try appending an element thats not of the arrays original type.

E.g. you will see an error if you try to append an `Int` to an array of string `[String]`.