# Looking to clean up this switch statement off an `Any` value from `valueForKeyPath`

Tags: swift, switch-statement

Basically I'm using KVC, and have potentially different value types returned, and want to create a switch statement based on the type

I tried the answer here, but it wouldn't compile:
[Swift: Test class type in switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724527/swift-test-class-type-in-switch-statement)

```
        var value: String = "Unknown"
        switch node.value(forKeyPath: keyPath) {
        case let numberValue is NSNumber:
            if numberValue == 0 {
                value = "No"
            } else if numberValue == 1 {
                value = "Yes"
            }
        case let stringValue is String:
            value = stringValue
        default:
            break
        }
```

it says

> "Pattern variable binding cannot appear in an expression"

and

> "Cast from <> to unrelated 'NSNumber' always fails"

This code here works for me:

```
        var value: String = "Unknown"
        let nodeValue = node.value(forKeyPath: keyPath)
        switch nodeValue {
        case is NSNumber:
            if let numberValue = nodeValue as? NSNumber {
                if numberValue == 0 {
                    value = "No"
                } else if numberValue == 1 {
                    value = "Yes"
                }
            }
        case is String:
            if let stringValue = nodeValue as? String {
                value = stringValue
            }
        default:
            break
        }
```

but it seems a little un-optimal that I need to use optional bindings to typecast a new variable

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: that appears to create another problem, "binary operator can't be applied to "Any?" and "NSNumber"

Comment: before entering the switch, try using `guard` on the value received from your  `valueForKeyPath`. After that, you won't need to typecast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a way to pattern match and cast all at once, and I think it's actually quite clean:

```
switch nodeValue {
case let number as NSNumber:
    switch number {
    case 0: value = "No"
    case 1: value = "Yes"
    default: break
    }
case let string as String:
    value = string
default: break
}
```

Comment: `let value: String
switch node.value(forKeyPath: keyPath) { {
case let number as NSNumber:
    value = number == 0 ? "No":"Yes"
case let string as String:
    value = string
default: value = "unknown"
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Totally, as long as he's okay with numbers 2 & up being "Yes" instead of "Unknown".

Comment: Looks like a Bool so he could also cast it as a Bool

Comment: it is a Bool that we store as a NSNumber :)

Comment: @AO so just cast it as Bool

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
guard let unwrappedValue = node.value(forKeyPath: keyPath) else {
   return
}

switch (unwrappedValue) {
   case is String:
       value = (unwrappedValue as! String)
   case is NSNumber:
       value = (unwrappedValue as! NSNumber) == 0 ? "YES" : "NO"
   defualt:
       value = "default value?"
}
```