# Switch case on Swift generics not able to identify the object type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

I am showing a tableview with the list generated using the following code. The UI is properly populated. However on did select method, the call is not matched inside the generic case.

```
@objc public protocol ListProtocol {}


class EmptyListProtocol:ListProtocol {
    let message:String
    
    init(message:String){
        self.message = message
    }
}


class ListItemStrategy<T>: ListProtocol{
    let object:T
    
    init(listitem:T) {
        self.object = listitem
    }
}

struct CartInfo {
    let card_id : String
    let productname: String
    let purchasedate:String
}

struct ProductOnSale {
    
    let product_id:String
    let product_name:String
    let store_id:String
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let item = self.tablelist[indexPath.row]
        switch item {
        case is ListItemStrategy<Any>:
            print("didtap")            
        case is EmptyListProtocol: break
        default:
            break
     }
}

var table list : [ListProtocol] = []
```

I am not able to detect in particular, if a cart is selected or new purchase product is selected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: Test class type in switch statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724527/swift-test-class-type-in-switch-statement)

Comment: How is `tablelist` declared?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson declared as var tablelist : [ListProtocol] = []

Comment: Be aware that generics are not covariant, this means that any type passed in `ListItemStrategy<T>` is **never** `ListItemStrategy<Any>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When checking the type you need to understand that *SomeGeneric<Any>* is a specific type and that you can't use the protocol `Any` here as something that represents *any* implementation of the generic type.

This means your `switch` would need to be something like

```
switch item {
    case is ListItemStrategy<ProductOnSale>:
        ...
    case is ListItemStrategy<CartInfo>:
        ...
    case ...
}
```

I assume you want to access the specific objects which mean you need to type case `item` so it might be preferable to skip the switch and use `if let` to cast directly

```
let item = self.tablelist[indexPath.row]

if let cartInfo = item as? ListItemStrategy<CartInfo> {
    ...
} else if let productOnSale = item as? ListItemStrategy<ProductOnSale> {
    ...
} else if let ... {
    ...
}
```

Here is a simple example

```
let tableList : [ListProtocol] = [
    ListItemStrategy(listitem: ProductOnSale(product_id: "product1", product_name: "", store_id: "")),
    ListItemStrategy(listitem: CartInfo(card_id: "card1", productname: "", purchasedate: "")),
    ListItemStrategy(listitem: ProductOnSale(product_id: "product2", product_name: "", store_id: "")),
    ListItemStrategy(listitem: EmptyListProtocol(message: "Empty"))
]

for item in tableList {
    if let cartInfo = item as? ListItemStrategy<CartInfo> {
        print(cartInfo.object.card_id)
    } else if let productOnSale = item as? ListItemStrategy<ProductOnSale> {
        print(productOnSale.object.product_id)
    } else if let emptyMessage = item as? ListItemStrategy<EmptyListProtocol> {
        print(emptyMessage.object.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. Fortunately I was able to figure out myself and the solution is exactly what you have added above