# Swift cast generic without knowing the type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is it possible to typecast an object like so (let the code speak for itself):

```
protocol Parent {
    ...
}

class Child<LiterallyAnyValue, SameAsThePrevious>: Parent {
    ...
}
```

And then when using it:

```
func foobar(parent: Parent) {
    if parent is Child { //ONE
        print(parent as! Child) //TWO
    }
}
```

At the signed points xcode wants me to supply the two types of "Child" within <> like Child<Int, String>...

The problem is that those types could be anything... LITERALLY
(And I've tried Child<Any, Any> but that doesn't work in this case)

Is there a workaround or a solution to this?

-------- Clarification --------

I am working on an iOS 7 project so I can't really use any modern library :)
That is including PromiseKit and Alamofire and the app has to make tons of http requests. The use promises in requests has grown on me, so I created my own Promise class.

At first I made it so that the Promise class would not be a generic and it would accept Any? as the value of the resolution procedure.
After that I wanted to improve my little Promise class with type clarification so the class Promise became "class Promise<T>"

In my implementation the then method created a PromiseSubscriber which then would be stored in a Promise property called subscribers.

The PromiseSubscriber is the protocol here that has two subset classes, one being PromiseHandler (this is called when the promise is resolved), and the other the PromiseCatcher (this is called when the promise is rejected)

Both PromiseSubscriber subset classes have a property called promise and one called handler.
These classes are also generics so that you know what kind of Promise they store and what is the return type of the handler.

In my resolution process I have to check if the PromiseSubscriber is a (let's say) PromiseHandler and if it is then call the handler that returns something and then resolve the subscribed promise with that value.

And here is the problem. I can't check if the subscriber is a catcher or a handler...

I hope it's clear enough now. Maybe this is not the right approach, I honestly don't know I am just trying to create something that is fun and easy to use (code completion without checking the type).

If it's still not clear and you are willing to help me, I'll send over the classes!

Comment: What do you mean by "SameAsThePrevious?" Do you mean that the two type parameters *must* always be the same (in which case, why are there two?) Or do you mean that you want to do certain things when they are the same? And do you know at compile time if they're the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Match the data type of a object in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444126/match-the-data-type-of-a-object-in-swift)

Comment: I don't believe this duplicates that question; the key part of this question is the fact that Child is generic on an unknown type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand what you're really trying to do here (please tell me it's something other than JSON parsing; I'm so tired of JSON parsing and it's the only thing people ever ask about), but the short answer is almost certainly no. Some part of that is probably a misuse of types, and some part of that is a current limitation in Swift.

To focus on the limitation in Swift part, Swift lacks higher-kinded types. It is not possible to talk about `Array`. This is not a type in Swift. You can only work with `Array<Int>` or `Array<String>` or even `Array<T>`, but only in cases where `T` can be determined at compile time. There are several ways to work through this, but it really depends on what your underlying problem is.

To the misuse of types side, you generally should not have `if x is ...` in Swift. In the vast majority of cases this should be solved with a protocol. Whatever you were going to do in the `if`, make it part of the `Parent` protocol and give it a default empty implementation. Then override that implementation in `Child`. For example:

```
protocol Parent {
    func doSpecialThing()
}

extension Parent {
    func doSpecialThing() {} // nothing by default
}

class Child<LiterallyAnyValue, SameAsThePrevious>: Parent {}

extension Child {
    func doSpecialThing() {
        print(self)
    }
}

func foobar(parent: Parent) {
    parent.doSpecialThing()
}
```

---

Thanks for the clarification; Promise is a great thing to play with. Your mistake is here:

> In my resolution process I have to check if the PromiseSubscriber is a (let's say) PromiseHandler and if it is then call the handler that returns something and then resolve the subscribed promise with that value.

Your resolution process should not need to know if it's a handler or a catcher. If it does, then your PromiseSubscriber protocol is incorrectly defined. The piece it sounds like you're missing is a Result. Most Promise types are built on top of Result, which is an enum bundling either success or failure. In your scheme, handlers would process successful Results and ignore failing results. Catchers would process failing results and ignore successful Results. The promise resolution shouldn't care, though. It should just send the Result to all subscribers and let them do what they do.

You can build this without a Result type by using a protocol as described above.

```
protocol PromiseSubscriber {
    associatedType Wrapped // <=== It's possible you've also missed this piece
    func handleSuccess(value: Wrapped)
    func handleFailure(failure: Error)
}

extension PromiseSubscriber {
    func handleSuccess(value: Wrapped) {} // By default do nothing
    func handleFailure(failure: Error) {} 
}

class PromiseHandler<Wrapped> {
    func handleSuccess(value: Wrapped) { ... do your thing ... }
}

class PromiseCatcher {
    func handleFailure(failure: Error) { ... do your thing ... } 
}
```

I recommend studying [PinkyPromise](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/PinkyPromise). It's a nice, simple Promise library (unlike PromiseKit which adds a lot of stuff that can make it harder to understand). I probably wouldn't use a protocol here; the associatedtype makes things a bit harder and I don't think you get much out of it. I'd use Result.

Comment: Okay so clarification time :)

Comment: Just a sec and I'll try to send more info

Comment: I just updated the question description, I hope everything will be clear now

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally managed to create a working version of my promise library. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic type in your foobar function, the one below requires the `parent` parameter to conform to the `Parent` protocol and `T` will represent the class of the object passed.

```
func foobar<T: Parent>(parent: T) {
    print(parent)
}
```

Comment: Is this gonna make me able to use the properties and methods defined in the Child class inside the foobar?