# How can I test if an instance is a specific class or type in Swift?

Tags: swift

Objective-C has two methods to test if an object is an instance of a specific class or a subclass:

```
- (BOOL)isMemberOfClass:(Class)aClass;
```

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an
>   instance of a given class.

```
- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass;
```

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an
>   instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from
>   that class.

In Swift I can test for the latter by using the `is` operator:

```
if myVariable is UIView {
    println( "I'm a UIView!")
}

if myVariable is MyClass {
    println( "I'm a MyClass" )
}
```

How can I test if an instance is a specific class or type in Swift (even when dealing with no NSObject subclasses)?

Note: I'm aware of `func object_getClassName(obj: AnyObject!) -> UnsafePointer<Int8>`.

Comment: `if myVariable is UIView ` doesn't need myVarible to be an instance of NSObject subclass.

Comment: @Kreiri Yes, but I'm looking for a solution that works with any kind of classes. UIView is just an example that is testable with `isKindOfClass`. Added another more generic example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you find out the type of an object (in Swift)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift)

Answer (score 7):

See my answer at (possible duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365978/195691:
It's now possible to compare identity of dynamic types in Swift:

```
myVariable.dynamicType === MyClass.self
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3+ we can do this using type(of: T) function.

```
let view = UIView()
if type(of: view) == UIView.self {
    print("view isMember of UIView")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `object_getClassName()`, invariants can be maintained by using a definitional equality in conjunction with `object_getClass()`

```
object_getClass(X()) === object_getClass(X()) // true
object_getClass(X()) === object_getClass(Y()) // false
```

Comment: In your gist, `X` and `Y` are not related.

Comment: There.  A much better solution (that isn't nearly as harebrained).