# isMemberOfClass in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

The keyword `is` is equivalent to `isKindOfClass`.

But I am unable to find what is equivalent of `isMemberOfClass` in swift.

Note:
My question is not about the difference between `isKindOfClass` or `isMemberofclass` rather the question is about what is the equivalent of `isMemberofClass` in Swift

somebody please clarify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK difference between isKindOfClass and isMemberOfClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653929/iphone-sdk-difference-between-iskindofclass-and-ismemberofclass)

Comment: No Its not duplicate because I am enquiring the equivalent of **isMemberOfClass**

Comment: Then check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25476740/6541007).

Comment: swift 3: ``.isMember(of:type)``

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking for `type(of:)` (previously `.dynamicType` in Swift 2).

Example:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog : Animal {}
class Cat : Animal {}

let c = Cat()

c is Dog // false
c is Cat // true
c is Animal // true

// In Swift 3:
type(of: c) == Cat.self // true
type(of: c) == Animal.self // false

// In Swift 2:
c.dynamicType == Cat.self // true
c.dynamicType == Animal.self // false
```

Comment: use of unresolved identifier `type` error gets thrown

Comment: You're using Swift 2. In Swift 3 it's `type(of: c)` in Swift 1 & 2 it was `c.dynamicType`

Comment: Thanks you saved my day !

Answer (score 2):

In case of optional variable `type(of:)` returns the type from initialization.

Example:

```
class Animal {}
class Cat : Animal {}

var c: Animal?
c = Cat()

type(of: c) // _expr_63.Animal>.Type
type(of: c) == Cat?.self // false
type(of: c) == Animal?.self // true
```

My class was inherited from `NSObject`, so I used its variable `classForCoder` and it worked for me.

```
class Animal : NSObject {}
class Cat : Animal {}

var c: Animal?
c = Cat()
c?.classForCoder == Cat.self // true
```