# Swift too smart? Checking an objects type when testing with XCTest

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, xctest

I am aware there are a number of questions on how to get the type of an object using Swift.

For example: [How do you find out the type of an object (in Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift)

The reason that I want to find the type is so that I can test that the correct thing is returned within a unit test. The premise being if anyone ever changes it, the test will fail, and we will know to be more careful.

Swift has the `is` method which returns a boolean as to whether an object is of a certain type. I would like to use is, and then assert that the response is true.

As outlined here (http://www.raywenderlich.com/74138/swift-language-faq) however, and shown in practice.. this throws up an error:

> error: 'is' test is always true

The point is that it returns true now.. and i am writing a test so that this is always the case. Stupid swift.

Any ideas how I can test the type of a response using XCTest and swift?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To get around Swift being too smart, cast the item you are testing to type `Any` and then test it.  For instance, if you want to assert that the function `fred()` returns an `Int`

```
func fred() -> Int {
    return 3
}

assert((fred() as Any) is Int)
```

Try this in a Playground, and then change the return type to `Float` and the assert will fire.

Answer (score 11):

Just use *is* operator:

```
XCTAssertTrue(viewController  is HomeViewController)
```

Comment: As fas as I understood, this is exactly what the question author does.

Answer (score 0):

I think @vacawama 's `XCTAssertTrue((value as Any) is Int)` notiation is good
and
@Javier Calatrava Llavería 's notation is also good.

but I decide use just String of `type(of:)`.
It's **Simple** and **Readable**.

look following cases.

```swift
// Simple And Readable notation
XCTAssertEqual("\(type(of: response))", "DataResponse<Int, Error>")
XCTAssertEqual("\(type(of: transformed))", "DataResponse<Double, Error>")

// @vacawama 's notation
XCTAssertTrue((response.value as Any) is Optional<Int>)
XCTAssertTrue((transformed.value as Any) is Optional<Double>)
```

And
You can make convenience Test AssertType Method like this.

```swift
// It's MORE Simple And Readable
KITAssertEqualType(response, "DataResponse<Int, Error>")
KITAssertEqualType(transformed, "DataResponse<Double, Error>")

public func KITAssertEqualType<T>(
    _ expression: @autoclosure () throws -> T,
    _ typeDescription: any StringProtocol,
    _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
    file: StaticString = #filePath, line: UInt = #line
) {
    XCTAssertEqual("\(type(of: try expression()))", String(typeDescription), message(), file: file, line: line)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are explicit about types in your let declarations, maybe you don't need to do anything more complex?

```
let fred: Int = fred()
```

Sure, it'll keep your tests from compiling instead of failing when they're run. But it communicates the same "Something in this test is no longer as expected!"