# How do I type check, without including subclasses?

Tags: ios, swift, typechecking, downcast

I want to know if an object is a type without including its subtypes. For example:

```
class Dog {

}

class Labrador: Dog {

}

//I want this to be false
if pet is Dog {

}
```

Comment: Is `pet` a Labrador?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102130/156811