# Is there an easy swift-like way to match an exact class in a case statement?

Tags: swift

I have done this:

```
func doSomething(anObject: AnyObject)
{
    switch anObject {
    case let myObj as MyClass:
        println("Is a kind of MyClass")
    case let yourObj as YourClass:
        println("Is a kind of YourClass")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Which works as you'd expect, classes and subclasses of `MyClass` or `YourClass` cause the relevant print statements to be executed.

However, I have a case where I want it to match an exact class (not any subclass of that class). Ideally I want something as simple and elegant as the `case let myObj as MyClass:` line, something like `case let myObj as exactly MyClass:`. Is something like this possible in Swift? Otherwise, what is the most elegant and concise way to achieve this within a case statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you find out the type of an object (in Swift)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

```
class A {}
class B: A {}

let b = B()

let b_is_exactly_a = b.dynamicType === A.self // false
let b_is_exactly_b = b.dynamicType === B.self // true
let b_is_a = b is A // true
let b_is_b = b is B // true
```