# How to check object belong to class or struct in swift

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct

I got stuck by the question in swift. Suppose I have one object, how to check whether it is from struct or class in swift.

Comment: Looks like it's impossible to do in Swift 3. However class object have **superclass** property and struct objects haven't.

Answer (score 15):

In Swift 3.0, you can call  `Mirror(reflecting:x).displayStyle` where `x` is your value of interest. The result will be `class`, `struct`, `enum`, `dictionary`, `set`... see the documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror.displaystyle

Code sample:

```
struct SomeStruct {
     var name: String
     init(name: String) {
          self.name = name
     } 
} 
var astruct = SomeStruct(name:"myname") 
Mirror(reflecting:astruct).displayStyle == .struct // will be true
Mirror(reflecting:astruct).displayStyle == .class; // will be false

class MyClass {
      var name:String
      init(name: String) {
          self.name=name
      }  
} 
var aclass = MyClass(name:"fsdfd")   
Mirror(reflecting:aclass).displayStyle == .struct // will be false
Mirror(reflecting:aclass).displayStyle == .class // will be true
```

Of course, it would be best handled using a switch-case statement in practice.

Answer (score 9):

This approach has been working for me in Swift 3:

```
class TestClass { }
struct TestStruct { }

var mystery:Any

mystery = TestClass()
// Is mystery instance a class type?
print(type(of:mystery) is AnyClass ? "YES" : "NO") // prints: "YES"

mystery = TestStruct()
// Is mystery instance a class type?
print(type(of:mystery) is AnyClass ? "YES" : "NO") // prints: "NO"
```

Note that this approach tells you only if an instance is a class type or not. The fact that it's *not* a class doesn't necessarily mean it's a struct (could be an enum, closure, tuple, etc.) But for most purposes and contexts this is enough to know if you are dealing with a reference type or a value type, which is usually what is needed.

Comment: Only if you know it is not a closure, because they are reference types too.

Answer (score 4):

There is `is` operator.

```
if someInstance is SomeType {
    // do something
}
```

And there is `as?` operator.

```
if let someInstance = someInstance as? SomeType {
    // now someInstance is SomeType
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In swift4, checking class or struct

```
class TClass {}
struct TStruct {}

func who(_ any: Any) -> String {
    if Mirror(reflecting: any).displayStyle == .class {
        return "Class"
    } else {
        return "Struct"
    }
}

print(who("Hello")) // Struct
print(who(TClass())) // Class
print(who(TStruct())) // Struct
print(who(1)) // Struct
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by below given way and [for more information on this please follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102130/3824808).

```
class Shape {
    class func className() -> String {
        return "Shape"
    }
}

class Square: Shape {
    override class func className() -> String {
        return "Square"
    }
}

class Circle: Shape {
    override class func className() -> String {
        return "Circle"
    }
}

func getShape() -> Shape {
    return Square() // hardcoded for example
}

let newShape: Shape = getShape()
newShape is Square // true
newShape is Circle // false
newShape.dynamicType.className() // "Square"
newShape.dynamicType.className() == Square.className()
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple example for this:

```
  var name = "Big Hero"
        if name.isKindOfClass(NSString){

            println("this is this class")

        }else{

            println("this is not this class")
        }
```