# What should dynamicType return in Swift?

Tags: swift, dynamictype

I have just started learning Swift and came across the function dynamicType which should return the type of a variable according to its values. But for me, it returns only "(Metatype)" for all the variables. Can anyone tell me if it is what it should return ? If it's not correct then why is it working wrong. I am using XCode version 6.1.1.

This is what I have written

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

str.dynamicType
```

Output:

```
Hello, playground

(Metatype)
```

Comment: You should first update your Xcode which is totally outdated

Comment: To know the type of object. refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift)

Comment: It _logs_ only "(Metatype)" (in your very primitive version of Xcode/Swift), but that is not what it actually _is_.

Answer (score 4):

A Metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types, structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types. You may not be able to print the name here because its not a string dataType. The purpose of dynamicType is to use it for runtime comparison like following.

```
if someInstance.dynamicType === SomeClass.self {
```

For more information see following link. If you really want to print the name of your custom classes then create "class func printClassName()" as suggested in the link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html