# Method that returns object of type which was called from

Tags: ios, swift, generics

So I have two classes `Base` and `More` which looks like this

```
class Base:NSObject {
    class func whatsMineType() -> Base {
        return Base()
    }
}

class More:Base {

}
```

And if I call method `Base.whatsMineType()` and `More.whatsMineType()` both of them gave me object of type `Base`. Is there a way to modify method `whatsMineType()` , without overriding it in `Base`, so it would return object of type which was called from?

My goal is that `Base.whatsMineType()` would return `Base` type object and `More.whatsMineType()` would return `More` type object.

I've tried with generic types but I don't have much experiance with them. Any suggestions will be super appreciated.

**Edit**

As I tried to explain this isn't the point of finding correct type but rather how to instantiate object with correct one.

Comment: Why don't you override whatsMineType in More?

Comment: Because I have much more types that extends `Base` and I don't want to override `whatsMineType()` in every single one. That's why `Base` is for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you find out the type of an object (in Swift)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift)

Comment: @WMios I think this isn't the point of finding correct type but rather how to instantiate object with correct one.

Comment: You've hard coded into it to always return Base instead of the objects type.

Comment: @WMios and also ask a question how should I do it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're at static scope, you can simply call `self.init()` to do this. You'll also have to define a `required` initialiser to ensure that all subclasses can be constructed with it.

```
class Base : NSObject {

    // mark init() as required to ensure that all subclasses can be constructed with it
    required override init() {}

    class func whatsMineType() -> Self {
        return self.init()
    }
}

class More : Base {}

let b = Base.whatsMineType()
print(type(of: b)) // Base

let m = More.whatsMineType()
print(type(of: m)) // More
```

Comment: And that what I was looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: @JoeBlow Indeed it has, thanks for prompting (I didn't quite have the energy to update all my answers when Swift 3 came out :) )

Answer (score 0):

The function `whatsMineType()` does not return a type (which it may should), but an object of that type. All it does, is to initialize an object of that type.

You should use an initializer for this:

```
let base = Base()
let more = More()
```

As it is a class function, the function is redundant, as you need to call it directly on the type, so you could just use the type then.

If you want to get the type of a class to pass it as a variable, you can use

```
let baseType = Base.self
let moreType = More.self
```

When you want to instantiate an object from its type, just use

```
let base = baseType.init()
let more = moreType.init()
```

But you might consider using generics instead.