# Different class type

Tags: swift, class, types, switch-statement, return

I´m making a mathematical quiz game. In the game the user selects a unit and then the game ask questions about exercises of this unit.

The classes I have are:

- ViewController
- UnitSelector - is responsible for inform the unit that the user
  has selected
- Unit01…to…Unit20 - are responsible for return randomly one
  exercise of the unit

And lots of  exercises

```
class UnitSelector {

      var unit: Int!

      init(unit: Int) {
        self.unit = unit
      }

      func getUnitClass() -> Any? {
        switch unit {
        case 0:
          return Unit01()
        case 1:
          return Unit02()
        // all the other cases
        case 19:
          return Unit20()
        default:
          return nil
        }
      }
    }

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    // more code
    unitSelector = UnitSelector(unit: selectedUnit)
    unitClass = unitSelector.getUnitClass()
    let question = unitClass.giveMeQuestion()
  }

  // all the other code
}

// all the Units are like this one
class UnitXX {
  // vars

  func giveMeQuestion() -> String {
    // code

    return "Question"
  }
}
```

The problem is that I don´t know how to solve this situation:
I´ve divided it in Units and each unit has its own exercises. I´ll have about 20 Units and in each unit about 5 exercises. In the controller the unitClass´s type is Any and I need to have the class that the UnitSelector.getUnitClass returns, Unit01()...Unit20().
I don´t know if the logic that I followed is the correct, so if someone can help me...

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe introduce a closure property `exercice` in `Unit` and set it when initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not totally clear for me, but I try to help:
You can get the type of the class by:

```
type(of: yourObject)
```

mentioned in this post:
[How do you find out the type of an object (in Swift)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift)

Have a lot of (in my opinion) better solution for that problem. One is an array-based approach:

```
//questions is an array with other array inside
var questions: [[String]] =
    [
        ["Question 1 for unit type One",
         "Question 2 for unit type One",
         "Question 3 for unit type One",
         "Question N for unit type One"],

        ["Question 1 for unit type Two",
         "Question 2 for unit type Two",
         "Question 3 for unit type Two",
         "Question 4 for unit type Two",
         "Question N for unit type Two"],

        ["Question 1 for unit type N",
         "Question 2 for unit type N",
         "Question N for unit type N"]
    ]

//getting random number between 0 and the count of the questions "outter" array
var randomUnitNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))

//getting the "inner" array with questions
var questionsForUnit = questions[randomUnitNumber]

//getting random number between 0 and the count of the questions "inner" array
var randomQuestionNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionsForUnit.count)))

//getting the question
var randomQuestion = questionsForUnit[randomQuestionNumber]

//printing the question
print(randomQuestion)
```

I hope this will be helpful!