# Cannot cast/decode data from server into Swift data model?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, decoding

I need to cast the below response from my server as [UserResult] but I cannot get it to work??

What am I doing wrong?

```
 func userSearch(keyword: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[UserResult], ResponseError>) -> Void ) {
        socket.emit("userSearch", keyword)
        
        socket.on("userFound") { ( data, ack) in
               print(data) // prints below NSArray
            if !data.isEmpty {
                if let response = data as? [UserResult] {
                   print("USERS \(response)") // WILL NOT WORK?
                   completion(.success(response))
                }
            } else {
                completion(.failure(.badRequest("No users found")))
            }
        }
    }
```

**Data from server**

```
 [<__NSArrayM 0x60000040e5b0>(
{
    profileUrl = "www.address1.com";
    username = chrissmith;
},
{
    profileUrl = "www.address2.com";
    username = johnsmith;
},
{
    profileUrl = "www.address3.com";
    username = alicesmith;
}
)
]
```

**UserResult Model**

```
struct UserResult: Decodable {
    let username: String
    let profileUrl: String
}
```

Comment: It depends on how your dataset is encoded.  Just saying "Data from server" is not going to help.

Comment: The data looks a bit strange -- URLs have quotes, but usernames do not.

Comment: An `NSArray` cannot have `struct UserResult` instances in it, since `NSArray` can only hold objects.  You need to look at where `data` is coming from and work out what is really in the array so you can cast it to the right thing

Comment: are you using Socket.IO-Client-Swift library ?  https://cocoapods.org/pods/Socket.IO-Client-Swift

Comment: Yes I am using the Socket.IO Client Swift Library

Comment: I guess you have a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`. So if your lib doesn't provide more method, it should be: `let response = data.compactMap { aValue -> UserResult? in guard let aDict = aValue as? [String: Any] else { return nil }; guard let userName = aDict["username"] as? String, let profileUrl = aDict["profileUrl"] as? String else { return nil }; return UserResult(username: userName, profileUrl: profileUrl) }`

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using `Socket.IO` library and specifically method

```
    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
    ...
}
```

defined as

```
@discardableResult
open func on(clientEvent event: SocketClientEvent, callback: @escaping NormalCallback) -> UUID
```

using typealias:

```
public typealias NormalCallback = ([Any], SocketAckEmitter) -> ()
```

So basically at the and you are being returned data of type `[Any]` according to [documentation](https://nuclearace.github.io/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Typealiases.html#/s:8SocketIO14NormalCallbacka).
Since you do not know what is inside your data it is better for you to unwrap objects in your array one by one (instead casting it directly to `[UserResult]`) and try to find out what Type there are by comparing to some set of known types as some of answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101450/how-do-you-find-out-the-type-of-an-object-in-swift) suggest.
I would start with verifying the data structure with example code below , and only move on with casting to various type afterwards:
Lets assume example `data1` is your data:

```
let dict1 = ["profileUrl":"www.address1.com","username":"chrissmith"]
let data1: NSArray = [dict1]
//printed data1:
//  (
//        {
//        profileUrl = "www.address1.com";
//        username = chrissmith;
//    }
//  )

    if data1[0] as? [String:String] != nil {
    print("We found out that first object is dictionary of [String:String]!")
    }
    else if  data1[0] as? Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> != nil {
    print("We found out that first object is dictionary of mixed values!")
   } else {
    print("We found out that first object has different data structure")
   }
```

Hopefully this answer was at least a little bit helpfull, even though not providing direct easy solution for your problem.

Comment: Since the explanation fits, a way to do it would be `let response = data.compactMap { aValue -> UserResult? in guard let aDict = aValue as? [String: Any] else { return nil }; guard let userName = aDict["username"] as? String, let profileUrl = aDict["profileUrl"] as? String else { return nil }; return UserResult(username: userName, profileUrl: profileUrl) }`.